# Route in-call audio to A2DP headset

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, a2dp

How can I set up my Nexus 4 to receive Hangouts and phone call audio over a Bluetooth A2DP link? Even though my headphones are connected, in-call audio is routed to the earpiece or speaker and there's no option to send it over BT.

I've got Creative WP-350 headphones that support both A2DP and HSP but the headset profile audio quality is unusably low, leaving no other option but to disable it in Android BT settings.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately A2DP supports only stereo audio, it doesn't support two-way audio, i.e. your mic woud be useless if the calls were routed over A2DP. You'll have to enable HSP for call functionality.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that A2DP is unidirectional and I'm fine with having to hold the phone in hand like in speakerphone mode. The HSP audio quality in WP-350 is just unusable.

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to take a look at [SoundAbout](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix), an app that allows you to route any sound channel the way you like:

[image: SoundAbout Settings] [image: SoundAbout Settings]
<sup>*SoundAbout* Settings (source: *Google Play*; click images for larger variants)</sup>

As you see, you can decide for each channel specifically where it shall be routed to. So you could e.g. have the notifications go to the speaker, while music and calls are routed to your headset.

I'm not using this app myself, so I cannot tell first-hand how well it works. But it has a free version to test, so nothing to lose. If you like it, buy it, and get additional features. For more options on headset controlling apps, be welcome to [browse my lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=83) ;)

<sup>before you ask: no, I'm in no way affiliated with the app or its developers :)</sup>

Comment: The app does not seem to work in newer versions of Android. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Sorry, no idea – I'm not using anything alike as I have no need.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think....

I have a A2DP bluetooth adapter, if you route the output sound of the call to the A2DP, you are making the adapter like a earphone without mic, when the cellphone are the MIC and the earphone are the output...